# Code kata should be added to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, asking-questions, scope

The idea of Programming Puzzles & Code Golf is excellent. Putting-out challenges, submitting your take on the solution, receiving feedback. But it seems to be mainly code golf, and this then just seems to be a 'race to the bottom' for all the 'golfing languages'. These languages are great, but lets try to think about things through the lens of the beginner programmer for a moment...

What's the biggest thing a beginner programmer is lacking?

- Textbooks? No.
- Feedback? No - Stack Exchange has this covered.
- Tutorials? No. - The internet has this covered.
- Practice? YES

Absolute beginners need practice. To quote the [Code Kata site](http://codekata.com/):

> How do you get to be a great musician? It helps to know the theory, and to understand the mechanics of your instrument. It helps to have talent. But ultimately, greatness comes from practicing; applying the theory over and over again, using feedback to get better every time.

Languages like Java, or C++ are daunting for beginners. Especially 'self-taughts' who won't have the benefit of being thrown in at the deep end at a software company. Code golf isn't going to help - all those golfing languages? Fish? BrainF*ck? Eh? But *code kata* WILL help.

People can submit challenges, give them a [beginner|intermediate|advanced|whatever] rating. Then people can work away at them in their own time, submit their answers, share, discuss, receive constructive feedback...

How do we implement this into Programming Puzzles & Code Golf? Change the title to Code Kata, Puzzles & Golf?

I think PP&CG could be an excellent platform for beginners. I think this is the niche that desperately needs to be filled right now!

I have never commented on META before, so if there's anyone here that can help promote this (or however this works), I'd be grateful.

Comment: Have you had a look at [codereview.se]? They review code for quality rather than quantity, being in some ways our opposite. For beginners in a language it's a great way to get feedback on practice coding. That feedback is the one thing you can't get by just practising alone.

Comment: You should be fine to comment over here now. I assumed you already had a PP&CG user, which you didn't, causing this issue.

Comment: @Oded thanks, but I thought I was a PP&CG user too!!!

Comment: @trichoplax I am a user on Code Review. Yes, its good, but it does not propose challenges for people to work-on.

Comment: @JohnADurston ah - I should have checked that before commenting... Would Code Review Meta welcome a post on Kata suggestions, similar to their contest posts? It seems a perfect fit there, and hard to fit here.

Comment: You could propose a new challenge type/winning criterion. Fastest-code works well here. Smallest memory footprint could work but might be harder to measure. What you are proposing might be implemented as a winning criterion along the lines of "has fewest improvement suggestions when posted to Code Review" but I'm not sure how either site would respond to that...

Comment: @trichoplax Thats a good idea! Thanks for your help so far. And thanks for helping a new member feel a little less presumptuous!

Comment: You're welcome. If an idea doesn't work out, it can still be a useful way of figuring out how this site works. I'd recommend browsing the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=active#tab-top) to see the kind of feedback other ideas are getting.

Answer (score 12):

Code Katas are a great idea in general, but I don't see how they fit into this community. *The* main requirement for every challenge posted here is that it has to have an objective winning criterion. Code Katas are looking for *good* solutions, whatever that means in the language you're currently using. But that's something you can't really quantify. Whether any piece of code's style is good is entirely subjective.

Comment: Its a shame. But code kata is too good a thing not to try to make it work.

Comment: @JohnADurston You could make a proposal on Area 51.

Comment: @xnor I'd rather not create a new site. But I think PP&CG should become Code Kata, Puzzles & Golf. How do we ask for that?

Comment: @JohnADurston You already have and so far there doesn't seem to be a lot of support for it. No offence but proposing a change of scope *and* name of a community without even being a member of that community seems a bit presumptuous. If you can think of a way to fit code katas into PPCG's current guide-lines with an objective way to quantify the quality of a code kata solution, I'd be very happy to hear it, but I don't see how it's possible.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Sorry, I was just trying to be positive. I did originally ask the question on Stack Overflow Meta, or maybe it does belong on Area 51?

Comment: @JohnADurston Yes, proposals for new SE sites belong to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).